# how to create list using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to create an unordered list using jquery which should contain images as items and behind the images link should be given to a specific function

i.e onClick on the list item it should call certain function

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to construct the entire list in jquery. Where will the script be getting the images from and the links?

Answer (score 1):

If you must add using jquery:

```
$('body').append('<ul id="test" />');
$('#test').append('<li>'+data+'</li>')

$('ul li').click(function(){
    //onclick event
})
```